# Cannot read property '0' of undefined while looping through data in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an API that return data that looks like this :

```
"fileName": "data.txt",
"onlyInFile1": [
{
"_id": "60618e87c2077428e4fedde5",

"TERMINAL_ID": "Y6152114",
"EXTERNAL_STAN": "686824",
"TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "75000 MGA",
"TRANSACTION_DATE": "21/01/2021 11:11:53"
},
{
"_id": "60618e87c2077428e4fedde6",

"TERMINAL_ID": "Y6152114",
"EXTERNAL_STAN": "686844",
"TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "200000 MGA",
"TRANSACTION_DATE": "21/01/2021 12:06:25"
}]
```

I want to show it in a table using the code bellow :

```
 <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>CARD_NUMBER</th>
                <th>TRANSACTION_AMOUNT</th>
                <th>TERMINAL_ID</th>
                <th>EXTERNAL_STAN</th>
                <th>TRANSACTION_DATE</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr
                *ngFor="let row of MatchTransactions.onlyInFile1; let i = index"
              >
                <th>{{ row.CARD_NUMBER }}</th>
                <td>{{ row.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.TERMINAL_ID }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.EXTERNAL_STAN }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.TRANSACTION_DATE }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Here is the service I used :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Tansaction } from './Transactions';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CrudService {
  // Node/Express API
  REST_API: string = 'http://localhost:4000';
  // Http Header
  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  // Get all objects
  GetTransactions() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.REST_API}/trans-list`);
  }
  GetMatchingTransactions() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.REST_API}/trans-match`);
  }
  // Error
  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Handle client error
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      // Handle server error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

And the match-table.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CrudService } from '../../services/crud.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-match-table',
  templateUrl: './match-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./match-table.component.scss'],
})
export class MatchTableComponent implements OnInit {
  MatchTransactions: any = [];
  constructor(private crudService: CrudService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.crudService.GetMatchingTransactions().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.MatchTransactions = res;
    });
  }
}
```

For some reason, I get the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined angular`

what am I missing here, cause the `fileName` field works fine but the ònlyInfile1` one does not work.

Comment: Please share the code that *writes* to `MatchTransactions`.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with that part of the code because I can access the `fileName` and display it on angular

Comment: Again, please share the code - Especially when it comes to asynchronous tasks, there's a wide variety of errors people run into. I have an idea what might be wrong, but we can't give you a correct answer, if you don't provide the proper code.

Comment: i updated the question with what you asked for, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems you run into.

First of all, judging from the API response you gave us the type you specified for `MatchTransactions` is wrong (`MatchTransactions: any = [];`).

The correct type is

```
MatchTransactions?: {
  onlyInFile1: any[];
  fileName: string;
};
```

Now the next problem is that you manually subscribe to the observable returned by `CrudService.GetMatchingTransactions()`.
The better approach is to use the `async` pipe provided by angular. That way you will not have to worry about calling `.unsubscribe` or other possible leaks.

This is how you implement it

```
class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  MatchTransactions?: {
    onlyInFile1: any[];
    fileName: string;
  };

  constructor(
    private readonly _crudService: CrudService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.MatchTransactions = this. _crudService.GetMatchingTransactions();
  }
}

// Template
<tr *ngFor="let row of (MatchTransactions | async)?.onlyInFile1">
  // ...
</tr>
```

Within your service you may create an interface for the returned type, which you can re-use where you consume the data

```
export interface IMatchingTransactions {
  onlyInFile1: any[];
  fileName: string;
}

GetMatchingTransactions(): Observable<IMatchingTransactions> {
  return this.httpClient.get<IMatchingTransactions>(`${this.REST_API}/trans-match`);
}
```

You can then also change your `MatchTransactions` type-definition within the component to

```
MatchTransactions?: Observable<IMatchingTransactions>;
```

Now angular will take care of the initially `undefined` value, automatically subscribe to the observable and display the result.

Comment: Am getting `Type 'Observable<Object>' is missing the following properties from type '{ fileName: string; onlyInFile1: any[];` do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Probably the TS service infers the type from your service. Try to specify the actual return type in there (`Obervable<{...}>`)

Comment: How do I do that exactly? do you mind editing your original anwser

Answer (score -1):

Probably `MatchTransactions.onlyInFile1` is undefined, so when the ngFor directive tries to access `MatchTransactions.onlyInFile1[0]` you get that error.